# Free abelian group generated by a set

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, notation, free-abelian-group

Let $S$ be a set. Then one can construct the free abelian group with basis $S$ as the set of all functions from $S \to \mathbb{Z}$ with finite support: $$\mathbb{Z}^{(S)}:=\{f:S \to \mathbb{Z} \ | \ \mathrm{supp}(f) \ \text{has finite cardinality}\}.$$ One can define an addition on $\mathbb{Z}^{(S)}$ the usual way $$+:\mathbb{Z}^{(S)} \times \mathbb{Z}^{(S)} \to \mathbb{Z}^{(S)}, \ (f,g) \mapsto f+g$$ with $(f+g)(s):=f(s)+g(s)$ for all $s \in S$. This gives $\mathbb{Z}^{(S)}$ the structure of an abelian group. Now, every $f \in \mathbb{Z}^{(S)}$ can be written uniquely as $$f=\sum_{\{x \in S \ | \ f(x) \neq 0 \}} f(x) 1_x.$$ However, this does technically not have $S$ as a basis, but rather the functions $1_x$ for all $x \in S$. Surely, those are in $1:1$ correspondence with the elements of $S$, but does that allow for writing $\sum_{\{x \in S \ | \ f(x) \neq 0\}} f(x)x$, or is that incorrect? I have often seen this formal sum definition, which is why I suspect that it is correct, but I am unsure. I don't know what the existence of a set of formal sums would be, if there is any.

An alternative notation is to write $f$ as $$f=\sum_{x \in S} f(x)1_x$$ and mention that this sum is indeed finite. However, isn't this rather also a bit inaccurate?

As a somewhat related question: I wanted to remind myself why one can write $f=\sum f(x)1_x$ despite not "knowing" the $f(x)$. This was because one knows those exist and satisfy the condition that for all $s \in S$ $f(s)=(\sum f(x)1_x)(s)$. "Not knowing the elements" was a silly sidethought I had, I just wanted to make sure if my explanation here is correct, since this is kind of related.

Comment: I'm afraid maths is totally rife with these sorts of abuses of notation! When people say things like $\pi \notin \Bbb Q$, this is arguably completely trivial - $\pi$ is a real number, which is set-theoretically something horrific like an equivalence class of Cauchy sequences of rationals. So of course it's not a rational number! But what $\pi \notin \Bbb Q$ really means is "the real number $\pi$ does not lie in the image of the canonical inclusion map $\Bbb Q \hookrightarrow \Bbb R$". Similarly here, $S$ isn't actually a subset of $\Bbb Z^{(S)}$, but we can think of it as a subset canonically!

Answer (score 2):

If by "correct" or "incorrect" you mean "this exact formula is true in set theory", then yes, the formula
$$f=\sum_{\{x \in S \ | \ f(x) \neq 0 \}} f(x) x$$
is, strictly talking, "wrong", since the elements $x\in S$ are not elements of $\mathbb Z^{(S)}$. Now, if the set $S$ does not have an operation already, then people usually say something along the lines of "I will use the notation $x$ for $1_x$ whenever it is added to something or multiplied by a scalar".
That is because in this context, for any integer $n\in\mathbb Z$ the notation $nx$ could not possibly be confused with anything other than $n1_x$, and similarly the notation $3x+2y$ could not mean anything other than $3\cdot 1_x + 2\cdot 1_y$ (actually I think this last one is *more* confusing by the jusxtaposition of $3$ and $2$ with $1$).

Answer (score 2):

Starting wit a set $S$ we can go for finding an abelian group that is *free* over $S$.

This boils down to finding an abelian group $F(S)$ *together with* a function $\eta:S\to F(S)$ such that for every function $g:S\to A$ where $A$ denotes an abelian group there is a unique group homomorphism $\gamma:F(S)\to A$ with $g=\gamma\circ\eta$.

With $F(S):=\mathbb Z^{(S)}$ and $s\mapsto1_s$ as prescription for $\eta$ this is neatly accomplished, so an abelian group free over $S$ has been constructed.

You however want to see $S$ as *basis* of $F(S)$ or equivalently you want $\eta$ to be an inclusion so that $S\subseteq F(S)$.

Well, you could go for defining $F(S)$ as collection of finite sums of form:$$n_1s_1+\cdots+n_ks_k$$
where $n_i\in\Bbb Z$ and distinct $s_i\in S$ and $1s:=s$.

This $F(S)$ must then be equipped with an addition. Are things better now? Not really I would say. If e.g. we try to find a suitable way to define this addition then it is quite likely that $\mathbb Z^{(S)}$ pops up in our mind.

IMV it is better if you exchange the concept "$S$ basis of $F(S)$" for the more general "$F(S)$ free over $S$". I only see advantages.

---

Edit:

Let me add that in the situation described above the image of $S$ under $\eta$ is actually a basis of $F(S)$.

Comment: But can I really define $F(S)$ as a collection of finite sums as you suggest? Why should that exist? The only way I can see this is by defining each $1_s$ as $s$ by abuse of notation, but this feels really forced and I don't know if this is even allowed. Maybe it is justified as abuse of notation or whatever. If I understand you correctly, you suggest to drop the $S$ is a basis idea and only work with $F(S)$ is free over $S$ whenever I see this object occuring?

Comment: @MaxH Does $Bbb Z^{(S)}$ exists for you? Then you could interpret $n_1s_1+\cdots+n_ks_k$ as a smart way to denote the function sending $s_i$ to $n_i$ for $i=1,\dots,k$ and sending any other $s\in S$ to $0$. This is enough to confim "existence" (whatever that is). "...this feels forced...", indeed, so let us rather go for using $\Bbb Z^{(S)}$ directly. The "price" we pay for that is only that we do not have $S\subseteq F(S)$. I am saying that we loose nothing by paying that price and win generality.

Comment: @MaxH The OP is somehow  disturbed by $s\mapsto1_s$. I admit that $s\mapsto 1s$ is a disturbance of the same kind.